# Why does this update query not complete?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, query-optimization

I have 2 tables, customers (3000 rows) and phone_call_log (350 000 rows).

I need to materialize the time of last call to each customer, using the call log (faster for frontend searches)

Indexes are on:

- start_time (timestamp)
- callee(bigint(32) unsigned)
- caller(bigint(32) unsigned)
- phonenumber(bigint(32) unsigned)
- last_call(timestamp)

Running this query without the OR statement completes in < 2 seconds for either caller / callee columns, but with the OR in place, it will not complete (I've not allowed it to run longer than 30 minutes in testing).

```sql
UPDATE customers
SET customers.last_call = (
     SELECT max(phone_call_log.start_time)
     FROM phone_call_log
     WHERE phone_call_log.callee = customers.phonenumber
        OR phone_call_log.caller = customers.phonenumber
)
WHERE customers.phonenumber IS NOT NULL
  AND length(customers.phonenumber) > 6
  AND customers.phonenumber > 1000000;
```

Comment: Does it help if you use two sub-queries `set last_call = greatest((select max() where callee = ...), (select max() where caller = ...))` ?

Comment: @SalmanA You're a life saver `3023 rows affected in 4 s 221 ms` I didn't think of splitting them like that. If you repost that as an answer I'll accept it?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Does the execution plan tell you anything about problems?

Comment: @RaymondNijland You can't left join with group by in an update query, you must do a subquery to select max in an update statement with MySQL, See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @RaymondNijland You've just recommended not using a subquery and using a LEFT join so I don't think you've grasped the issue.  I'll bear in mind that you need more details to understand the limits of MySQL next time, but luckily Salman A understood the issue immediately and supplied a fantastic solution. Thanks for your opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries using `OR` cannot use index (as efficiently). I suggest you try the following:

```
UPDATE customers
SET last_call = GREATEST(
    (SELECT MAX(start_time) FROM phone_call_log WHERE callee = customers.phonenumber),
    (SELECT MAX(start_time) FROM phone_call_log WHERE caller = customers.phonenumber)
)
```

Be advised that [`GREATEST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) has issues with NULL values.

Comment: yes, to get around the null issue you need something like `nullif( greatest(  coalesce(  (subquery1), timestamp(0) ), coalesce( (subquery2), timestamp(0) ) ), timestamp(0) )`

Answer (score 0):

**Fastest**

Change the data flow to update `customers.last_call` when a call comes in.

**UPDATE JOIN**

`UPDATE` works better with a `JOIN` than `IN ( SELECT ... )`

**OR**

`OR` is a performance killer.  The query is likely to scan the entire `phone_call_log` each for each customer.

One fix is to do two `UPDATEs` and have suitable indexes:

```
UPDATE 
    SET customers.last_call = GREATEST( customers.last_call,
                 ( select max(phone_call_log.start_time)
                      FROM  phone_call_log
                     WHERE  phone_call_log.callee = customers.phonenumber 
                 )
    WHERE ...
UPDATE 
    SET customers.last_call = GREATEST( customers.last_call,
                 ( ... caller ... )
                 )
    WHERE ...
```

That needs these indexes on `phone_call_log`:

```
    INDEX(callee, start_time)
    INDEX(caller, start_time)
```

*and* remove your current 1-column indexes on caller and callee.

**Datatype**

It is probably wrong and counterproductive to use `BIGINT` for a phone number, especially in light of `LENGTH(customers.phonenumber) > 6`.

In fact, all of this boils down to a single test:

```
where customers.phonenumber is not null
  AND LENGTH(customers.phonenumber) > 6
  AND customers.phonenumber > 1000000;
```

Each of the `>` check for `NOT NULL` anyway; use only one of the others, depending on datatype.  And do have it indexed.

(Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; the 'English' is less precise.)